# How to detect sign in cancel event during restore?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When I call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` dialog asking to enter password for remembered user. I want to detect when from that dialog user hit cancel. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: I can. It was `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError` delegate method.

Comment: Oh yes. The error might hold some details. This question (and answer) deserves a vote-up.

Comment: You were right. Check for the error code as done by @iphonic below, but in the `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError` method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong, you can try doing the following, though I haven't tested it, but might help you.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error{

if (error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
   //Handle Cancel
}

}
```

Comment: This state is not called for a restore transaction. The error code is displayed in the paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError method itself